# Display bike routes on Android MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

I want to display a map with the bike layer displayed in a google MapView on Android. I see that you can add the real time traffic layer with

```
    mapView.setTraffic(true)
```

But it doesn't appear there is anything similar for the bike layer. Is there a way to do this? For reference, this is the map I want to display:

http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&ll=40.011707,-105.262413&spn=0.036419,0.084543&t=m&z=14&layer=t&lci=bike

I see that there is a URL parameter for the bike layer, so if worst comes to worst, I could use  WebView. In my testing, however, this method seems way too slow to build a usable app, so I would like to keep it in a MapView if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: You should check MAPVIEW with JSON, it'll help you.

Comment: Do you have any links to relevant usage, or maybe just a good intro to JSON? Ive never used it before. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, here is the technique in answer which you can use.